# enable MPMoviePlayerViewController airplay

Tags: ios, iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, airplay

I am trying to enable airplay in my application using setAllowAirplay but its showing below warning.

> MPMoviePlayerViewController may not respond to 'setAllowsAirPlay'

So please suggest how can I enable airplay in my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is there because not all iOS versions and devices include the allowsAirPlay property. The safe way to call it would be like this:

```
if ([moviePlayerVC.moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsAirPlay:)]) {
    [moviePlayerVC.moviePlayer setAllowsAirPlay:YES];
}
```

I'm pretty sure that this selector will exist on any modern iOS device.